# Can't make a view to be updatable (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of employees with their id, name and id of their boss

```
| emp_id | name   | boss_id |
|--------|--------|---------|
| 100    | John   | NULL    |
| 110    | Carl   | 100     |
| 120    | Andrew | 100     |
| 130    | Peter  | 100     |
| 140    | Chris  | 130     |
| 150    | Mary   | 120     |
| 160    | Wayne  | 110     |
```

Then I have to create a view that will show employee's name and a name of his/her boss. I use self join to make it done:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW emps_and_bosses
    AS SELECT e.name AS employee, b.name AS boss
    FROM employees e JOIN employees b ON e.boss_id = b.emp_id
```

And now if I want to update date in the view (set another name for example), it throws me an error:

```
ERROR:  cannot update view "emps_and_bosses"
DETAIL:  Views that do not select from a single table or view are not automatically updatable.
HINT:  To enable updating the view, provide an INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger or an unconditional ON UPDATE DO INSTEAD rule.
```

So the question is how can I create a view following conditions — using only one FROM base (without self join, to make the view updatable)?

Comment: Create a trigger or a rule as the message tells you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, one of the solutions is to use query that meets the conditions when a view can be updatable.

Instead of joins we need to use subqueries.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW emps_and_bosses  
AS SELECT name, (SELECT name FROM employees b WHERE b.emp_id = e.boss_id) AS boss
FROM employees e
```

This way the view we're creating is updatable by default.

Answer (score 1):

Just like the message and the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) (scroll to Updatable views) say, there are some conditions to have a view updatable.
Since you are using a `JOIN`, 1 of the conditions is not met.

The hint suggest to create a trigger or an unconditional rule, which is what I have done below.

```
CREATE RULE UpdateBoss AS ON UPDATE TO emps_and_bosses
DO INSTEAD
UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET name = new.employee, Boss_id = (SELECT emp_id from employees where name = new.boss)
WHERE name = old.employee
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: I imagine your `employees` table had a `primary key` on `emp_id` that the view does not show.
Be careful with the updates on the view as neither of your columns are unique, therefore you could very well be updating several records when you intend to update only 1.